# using nth-type or nth-child to select n element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

**Q**: What XPath or CSS selector I can use to select 2nd `<div class="checkbox">`?

I have tried to use:

- **XPath** - `//div[@class="checkbox"][2]`
- **CSS** - `div.checkbox:nth-child(2)`

However none of them worked on chrome developer tool.

- I can use `$x('//div[@class="checkbox"]')` to see all three checkboxes
- I can use `$x('//div[@class="checkbox"]')[0]` to specify the 1st `div.checkbox`
- I can use `$x('//div[@class="checkbox"]')[1]` to specify the 2nd `div.checkbox`

#### Here's an example of my HTML Structure

```html
<div class="fs">
    <div class="f">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" value="A">
            <label for="A">A</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="f">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" value="B">
            <label for="B">B</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="f">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" value="C">
            <label for="C">C</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to find the second element by index, another possibility would be to get it by the value on the INPUT or the text in the LABEL that is contained in that DIV. A couple XPaths would be

```
//div[@class='checkbox'][./input[@value='B']]
//div[@class='checkbox'][./label[.='B']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [JeffC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2386774/jeffc) and [Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) already suggested XPath way of doing it, I'd like to suggest a different approach.

In CSS, one can use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to choose 2nd `<div class="f">` and grab the nested div from there. (`>` can be omitted)

```
div.f:nth-child(2) > div.checkbox
```

Similarly, the following works in XPath:

```
//div[@class='f'][2]/div[@class='checkbox']
```

One *can* choose an element based on the attribute value with CSS selector using [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), but one *cannot* select the parent, unfortunately.

Comment: so I cannot select 2nd div with class checkbox directly?

Comment: @jacobcan118, if you want to use CSS selector only, and choose the element directly, you cannot select the 2nd `<div class="checkbox">` directly.

Since you are using Selenium, however, you _can_ use `driver.findElement*s*(By.Css("div.checkbox"))` to grab all `<div class="checkbox">`, then choose the div that you want. 

I'm not sure if the order of the elements are kept correctly in the list when you use `driver.findElements` though.

Comment: @jacobcan118, please let me know if you have further questions.
If my answer was helpful, please upvote/select as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need 2nd element from the results. Which can be done by using below

```
(//div[@class="checkbox"])[2]
```

I think CSS doesn't allow such a thing to select from a result